# Html.RenderAction works properly, yet direct request returns 404

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am developing MVC application with multiple areas. Everything works fine, except I can't display content of one of the areas, that is called `Scheme`.

In shortcut, this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Show error page", "Index", "Error", new { area="Scheme" });}
```

Return 404, as typing `host/Scheme/Error/` directly into browser.

However! This:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Error", new { area="Scheme" });}
```

renders action result content correctly and as expected on Layout page.

The same behaviour I noticed in every controller in this area.

- I have RegisterAllAreas() method called on the start of application
- I have deleted content of RegisterRoutes() in RouteConfig (although I'm not sure what does it do, just following tutorials).
- I one milion times checked, that controllers namespace in this area matches the one in RegisterArea() method.
- Before showing 404, application throws an error: "The controller for path '/Scheme/Error/Index' was not found or does not implement IController." (googled for that, none of the solutions on internet matches my problem)

SchemeAreaRegistration.cs:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication.Areas.Scheme
{
public class SchemeAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "Scheme";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Scheme_default",
            "Scheme/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "WebApplication.Areas.Scheme.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
}
```

ErrorController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication.Areas.Scheme.Controllers
{
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    // GET: Scheme/Error
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
@Html.ActionLink("your link", "Index", "Error", new { area = "Scheme" }, null)
```

or

```
@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { area = "AreaName" })
```

or

```
@Html.RouteLink("your link", new { action = "Index", controller = "Error", area = "Scheme" })
```

Comment: If you have read the question, you'd have known I used first one. Changing it doesn't do anything. The problem isn't generating route by razor, it works fine. The problem is, after querying correct route, there is application doesn't find controller.

Comment: Whether calling  from areas or  from seperate view which was outside the areas?

Comment: It is called from Layout page, which is under `Scheme` area. Notice, that calls to actions from areas other than `Scheme` works fine.

Comment: ok did you tried calling by without mentioning areas like this **@Html.Action("MenuItems", "Common", new {area="" })**

Comment: Why would I? It just give another, incorrect route.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107621/discussion-between-praveen-and-rico-w).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling this overload of Html.ActionLink:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText, string actionName, object routeValues);
```

Note that the first parameter (after *this*) is `linkText`, perhaps not what you intended or expected.

You probably should be calling this one:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName,
    object routeValues, object htmlAttributes);
```

Note that all overloads with `controllerName` require both routeValues and htmlAttributes to be present as well.
So your call would become:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click here", "Index", "Error", new { area="Scheme" }, null);
```

Comment: Ok, I rewrited code incorrectly. In application ActionLink has correct argument. The problem isn't generating route by razor, it works fine. The problem is, after querying correct route, there is application doesn't find controller.